# cannot invoke dispatch_get_global_queue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have this line of code:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, 0);
```

I get error

> Cannot invoke dispatch_get_global_queue with an argument list of type
>   (dispatch_queue_atr_t, Int)

Must be something I am missing...

**Update:**

When I use xcode codeinsight / dropdown of suggestions for what to input it suggests DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT of type dispatch_queue_attr_t - however, when going into code I can (now) see the paramater it expects is long.

I was interesed in getting a queue that was using multiple threads which IO tasks could be grouped into. (i.e. I do not want o "stall" the queue waiting on downloading some file.) I read tthat was possible here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Which mentions DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT - however, I think that is only used when creating own queues - I just did not realize this originally

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

All global queue

```
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH        2
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT     0
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW         (-2)
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND  INT16_MIN
```

Comment: When I use xcode codeinsight / dropdown of suggestions for what to input it suggests DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT of type dispatch_queue_attr_t - however, when going into code I can see the paramater it expects is long. I will try DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch_get_global_queue` takes `long` as 1st parameter, not an `dispatch_queue_attr_t` which is NSObject.

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatch_get_global_queue( long identifier, unsigned long flags);
```

As described in the document, you can specify [dispatch_queue_priority_t](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/dispatch_queue_priority_t) value or if your develop for iOS >= 8.0, you can use `QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, or QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_global_queue

Answer (score 1):

Use any one of this type of **dispatch_queue_priority_t**

```
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW,
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND
```

For more knowledge about queue :

Reference http://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency/

Hope it will help you :)